# O comando "sudo" funciona no Debian?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linux

Tentei executar o `sudo` no python e me retornou "bash: sudo: comando não encontrado", qual o problema?

Estou tentando usar o matplotlib e não estou conseguindo, então tentei instalar, executando:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

Meu python é 2.7.9, será esse o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente o sudo já está instalado, caso não esteja tente:

```
apt-get install sudo -y
```

mas antes você precisa estar como root, então:

```
su -
```

Verifique também se você não tem o sudo aqui:

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: Era isso, o sudo não estava instalado. Obrigado!